# SWTableViewCell Delegate Method is not calling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Which delegate method is being fired when I try to swap my SWTableView cell.
I wanted to swipe single cell at a time and if I try to swipe any cell, then the open cell should close.

Current Issue is, All cells are swiping but not closing automatically.

One Cell Should Swipe At A Time:

[image]

It should Swipe When Clicked on button

[image]

Comment: you have to swipe cell one at a time?

Comment: Exactly Yes! Birendra!

Comment: but default functionality of SWTableViewCell is same like you want

Comment: i have download that code and see

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41735037/3427565

This method is calling but not working.
even after writing this method, I will be able to swap multiple rows.
delegate method and all set . I am not getting why it is happening.

Comment: please put your code here

Comment: - (BOOL)swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe:(SWTableViewCell *)cell
{
    // allow just one cell's utility button to be open at once
    
      return YES;
}

Comment: can you come on skype or give me Gmail or any other thing where I can show you my whole code and class.

Comment: dobariyabirendra@gmail.com

Comment: send your code zip file

Comment: Thanks, i am sending.

Comment: ok i see the code and reply you

Comment: did you receive the zip?

Comment: you have use custom tableviewcell right

Comment: which class you have set for that "UITableViewCell" or  "SWTableViewCell"?

Comment: SWTableViewCell

Comment: cell.delegate = self; put this line in last and only one time

Comment: where should i write this?

Comment: before this line cell.lbl_detailEvent_CityName.text

Comment: please comment this code "    if (cell)
    {
        for (SWTableViewCell *cell in [_tableView_DetailEvent visibleCells])
        {
            [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
        }
    }
    

    
    
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[CustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }"

Comment: I tried your stuff.. but nothing effective, All going same "not working"

Answer (score 0):

Try this to automatically close Swipe Cell

```
-(BOOL)swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe:(SWTableViewCell *)cell {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have Written your given code then too it is not hiding.

-(BOOL)swipeableTableViewCellShouldHideUtilityButtonsOnSwipe:(SWTableViewCell *)cell {
    
    
    [cell hideUtilityButtonsAnimated:YES];
    
    return YES;
}

Comment: Delegate tableview cell <SWTableViewCellDelegate> ?

Comment: #import "DetailedEventShow.h"

@interface DetailedEventShow ()<SWTableViewCellDelegate>

"I have already set this  < SWTableViewCellDelegate > "

Comment: You Have create custome cell or programatically add on table?

Comment: try on table data Source Method cellForRowAtIndexPath Tablecell.delegate = self;

Comment: I have used Custom Cell

Comment: set the Tablecell.delegate=self ?

Comment: custome cell Parent class is @interface CommentCell : SWTableViewCell

Comment: Oops ok well I need the solution that is why I have requested you.
it's ok no problem, Well I have written your code in cellForRow but it is saying this error 

http://i68.tinypic.com/2mfkn7q.png

Comment: ok, please change in your customeTableviewCell.h file parent class to  SWTableViewCell. its wrong so please change it like this --> @interface CustomeTableViewCell : SWTableViewCell

Comment: It is already this one what you said.

https://s24.postimg.org/mbknnqe0l/Screen_Shot_2017_01_19_at_12_24_04_PM.png

Comment: ohkkk cell.delegate = self ;

Comment: https://s27.postimg.org/3lx6gdstv/Screen_Shot_2017_01_19_at_12_32_36_PM.png

Comment: Please have a look on above image link i have done your stuff but not working man.

https://s27.postimg.org/3lx6gdstv/Screen_Shot_2017_01_19_at_12_32_36_PM.png

Comment: I think rightUtilityButtons array Code add in to if(!cell)

Comment: like How? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @sohail

Answer Please!